# Connecting to remote host via mysql client cli

Tags: mysql, client, command-line-interface

I am trying to establish a remote database connection via the mysql client cli.

I am executing for example the following command:

```
mysql -h REMOTE_HOST
```

The problem I am having is that despite of specifying the REMOTE_HOST, "mysql" is still connecting to the local server and I really don't know why.

Only when I specify a different port than 3306, then the REMOTE_HOST is getting parsed:

```
mysql -h REMOTE_HOST --port 3308
```

I really have no idea what to do.
Inside the mysql config file "skip-networking" is not set and "bind-address" is set to "0.0.0.0".

But i think that these parameters are important for the mysql server and not client configuration, right?

Would be glad about your profound recommendations!

Thanks a lot and a great week!

Denis

PS:

mysql socket is used.

mysql --version returns:
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Ubuntu is used as OS.

Comment: Do you not specify a User and password?

Comment: Yes, to keep the case more clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Bind_address allows the server to listen on all interfaces, skip_networking would prevent it from accepting TCP/IP connections so both of those seem correct.

Does the remote MySQL server run on port 3308 or 3306? If it's the default port, 3306 then you don't normally need to specify that.

Comment: Hey tcoker,

i am interested about the mysql client, not the mysql server!

Best regards
Denis